# Break in a method called from a loop

Tags: java, methods, while-loop, break

I'm refactoring a very large method with a lot of repetition in it.

In the method there are many while loops which include:

```
    if ( count > maxResults){
        // Send error response
        sendResponse(XMLHelper.buildErrorXMLString("Too many results found, Please refine your search"), out, session);
        break;
```

I want to extract this as a method, because it happens 3 times in this one method currently, but when I do so I get an error on the break as it is no longer within a loop. The problem is that it is still necessary to break out of the while loops, but only when the maximum number of results are reached.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the method is :

```
public boolean test(int count, int maXResult) {
 if ( count > maxResults) {
        // Send error response
        sendResponse(XMLHelper.buildErrorXMLString("Too many results found, Please refine your search"), out, session);
        return true;
        }
return false;
}
```

Call method from loop as :

```
while(testCondition) {
    if (test(count, maxResults)) {
    break;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was missing the obvious.

Comment: It happens sometimes :) Happy to help.

Answer (score 3):

This is impossible to do directly.

Most often you want to break because you have found the solution and no longer have to search. So indicate in the called function that there is/was success, for instance by returning a result or a boolean to indicate success. And if the function returns success, then break.

Comment: Not at all. The function takes a task (for instance the deciding if the action was success, or enough and doing an action when it is) and the result of that is used to stop looking.

Comment: Thanks Thirler, just what I needed.

Comment: Yes, but if you haven't written the code and it's uncommented, it would be difficult to read it with a naked glance. In my opinion, I'd prefer to return a result for the function as you suggest, that's why I upvoted ;)

Comment: Ah I though you meant my suggestion was not possible instead of breaking in a function. Indeed if it were possible it is impossible to follow for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

If it is now within a method instead of the while loop have it return a value and then break based on that.

i.e.

```
public bool refactoredMethod(parameters)
{
    if ( count > maxResults){
    // Send error response
    sendResponse(XMLHelper.buildErrorXMLString("Too many results found, Please refine your     search"), out, session);

    return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to break the loop in the method using return;

Answer (score 0):

As Thriler says you cant do it directly. You could extract part of it to the method and do something like:

```
if(isTooManyResults(count)) { break; }
```

Obviously your isTooManyResults method would need to return `true` if there are too many results and `false` otherwise